# Regex expression to match alpha character as first character and the rest alphanumeric

Tags: regex

Im trying to write a regex to match the following:

```
must start with a letter
the rest must be alphanumeric 
at least one character in length
max characters 12
```

Should me able to match

```
a
k2jdj
hello
example72812
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. I recommend to read http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: well, this is quite easy :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,11}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was being dumb, i had been doing ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,12}$

Comment: oh.. there is a mistake (typo) in the answer, should be `0-9` pls fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

this?

```
 [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,11}
```